# Cinder block foundation dissolving from water

Tags: foundation, drainage

[image: Corrigagted pipe is from gutter above it and also joins one in the other corner at the back of the house. Exits to daylight about 6" or so underground to stone around the end of the pipe and does not seem to be blocked when i run water thru the gutter. This was put in about 3 years ago.]I discovered that water seems to be dissolving the cinder blocks in one corner of the addition we had put on the house back in 2005. Although I haven't excavated it yet, I can see at least 2 cinder blocks close to ground level are completely gone. Water must have been collecting in that corner the whole time. I never thought there would be any water issues there since it's built on a hill. I'd think it would drain away on its own, but apparently the water found its way under the foundation and collected near the front corner and had no way out. Builder never put any drain pipes around it or anything and i didn't know that it would even need that at the time. Anyway, depending on how much repair I have to do, I'm probably going to just pour concrete in there a bag at a time till I fill the missing cinder blocks. Before I do anything, though, I need a way to mitigate the water. Digging a hole for a sump pump will be difficult under the crawl space since it's only 6 blocks off the ground, then 3' underground to the footing. Since it's the low side of the hill, I wondered if I could just put some kind of drain pipe thru the foundation there and just let it run out to daylight? On the inside, there's no sign of the fill dropping off in that corner. Looks as it did the day I put gravel in and plastic sheeting over it. Would just running a drain pipe to daylight be a better option than a sump pump? Wondering if water collecting there is freezing over winter and cracking the blocks. who knows. I wedged some solid bricks under the corner just to help support it till i can dig it out and repair it (not shown in the photo). i'm recovering from neck surgery and am hoping to be able to get to this by the end of the month.

Comment: Pictures are almost always helpful

Comment: So is a little formatting. "Wall o'text" is never a good look and makes it hard to follow. Also, your title (which should be a question) has nothing to do with the questions you've asked.

Comment: end the piipe in a french drain or gravel pit instead of daylight.

Comment: You need to add proper drainage.  If it's groundwater, that's a separate issue.

Comment: Updated description and added a photo.